# Scope for containers in C++

Tags: c++, scope

Let's say I have something like the following piece of code:

```
int main() {
    vector< vector<int> > vecs;
    int n_vecs;
    cin >> n_vecs;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_vecs; i++) {
        int n_nums;
        cin >> n_nums;
        vector<int> tmp;
        for (int j = 0; i < n_nums; i++) {
            int num;
            cin >> num;
            tmp.push_back(num);
        }
        vecs.push_back(tmp);
    }
}
```

which populates a vector of `vector<int>`s gradually. From some testcases, I understand that after the `for` loops finish, the vector is constructed as expected. However, I can't understand why is that: shouldn't the `tmp` vector be
out of scope after the outer `for` loop finishes? Does a copy of it get inserted into the `vecs` vector? (The same applies for `map`s)

Comment: Yes, a copy of `tmp` is `push_back`ed. And to be more precise, `tmp` is constructed and destroyed for every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a copy is made. See [documentation for `push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> The new element is initialized as a copy of value

There are two overloads for the function. In your example, the `void push_back( const T& value )` overload is chosen because you are passing a named object and have not applied `std::move`, hence the copy.

If you passed an unnamed object or applied `std::move`, then the other overload would be chosen, "stealing" the contents of `tmp` to initialise the new object at the end of the `vecs` vector.

But that doesn't even matter for your question. In either case, the fact that `tmp`'s lifetime ends afterwards (because of its scope in the source code) is irrelevant. The `vecs` vector already contains and owns a new element, and what happens to `tmp` is none of its concerns.

---

Perhaps the most important thing to keep in mind is that C++ standard containers are designed so that you can use them as easily as plain `int`s. You can copy them, return them, pass them around and assign them, and the results will always be as expected. This is because C++ standard containers **own** their contents.

Comment: There is a lot of downvoting going on for this question. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Does a copy of it get inserted into the vecs vector?

Yes.